# Autocomplite crashes when I press enter on the current fill option when navigating from the keyboard

Tags: javascript, html, autocomplete, navigation, keyboard

I am trying to implement a field for entering the airport code and the city in which it is located, with auto-completion.
There are three ways to select the desired option to fill in from the list of suggestions: click on the desired one with the mouse, hang a tab or scroll through the arrows to the desired one and press enter. In the first two cases, everything is done correctly, and in the last one, my Codepen page is replaced with the inscription "Not Found".

This is the html code:

```
<form>
  <input autocomplete="off" name="user-input" class="suggest" placeholder="City or airport code"/>
</form>
```

In js part I use this code to track keyboard events, where `activeNumber` is a position of an active item in my suggest list and it is more or equal to zero only when navigating with arrows:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  let list = document.querySelector('.autocomplete-list');
  if (!list) {
    return;
  }
  
  list = list.querySelectorAll('.list-item');
  // enter
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    if (activeNumber < 0) {
      e.target.click();
    }
    else {
      list[activeNumber].click();
    }
  } else if (e.keyCode == 40) {
    activeNumber++;
    changeActive(list);
  } else if (e.keyCode == 38) {
    activeNumber--;
    changeActive(list);
  } 
})
```

It seems that the problem is not in the implementation of the click listener, because the enter, when selected via tab, also calls `click()`, but it works.
What could be the problem and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

When you click on enter, the form is submitted. I guess that's why you get not found.

Read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event

Try this to fix the problem:

```
<form onsubmit="submitForm(event)">
...
<script type="text/JavaScript">
  function submitForm(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.history.back();
  }
</script>
```